# LoginContext and callback in C#

Tags: c#, java, database, authentication, porting

I'm porting an application from Java to C#, and I have to convert the class used to authenticate the user to the main database; this is the main method:

```
public Map<String, String> authenticate(String username, String password, String domain) throws LoginException {
        LoginContext loginContext = null;
        try {
            String[] args = new String[] { username, password, domain };
            loginContext = new LoginContext("CfLogin", new CarrefourCallbackHandler(args));
            loginContext.login();
            Subject subject = loginContext.getSubject();
        } catch (javax.security.auth.login.LoginException e) {
            String message = "Login error";
            logger.debug(message, e);
            throw new LoginException(message, e);
        }
        return Collections.emptyMap();
    }
```

What am I supposed to use to replace the loginContext class? Could you link me a good guide to this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you probably want to replace this code using the Membership API in .Net

Heres a good starting point

[Membership Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx)